# downgraded from SLI, should I do anything special?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, crash, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I used to have SLI GTX 670, due to some rethinking and not really needing that much power I sold off one of the cards.

Everything has been working fine during games, but I get these random "Display Driver" has crashed/recovered messages where the screen just goes black and comes back.
All I'm doing is using Mozilla/Chrome,  just browsing or watching youtube (you see now why I didnt need the SLI, this is all I mostly do nowadays on the PC) and it usually crashes and comes back in a few seconds, there are those rare occurrences where Chrome locks up and all pages go white and my only option is to close process and restore.

Currently on the latest 337.88 drivers, this random crash has been going on for a while I sold the other card in February, just posting now as I'm curious to know if its fixable or just new driver issues.
Windows 7 64-bit Ult.Ed.
Nvidea GTX 670

EDIT: Sorry for completely derailing from my initial topic, My main concern is because all I did was turn off PC > remove SLI bridge and 2nd Card > Turn on PC > resume my everyday routine.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the drives, do a complete uninstall, this would remove any trace of your other profile.

Comment: I've used Drivesweeper, deleted all Nvidea items that were scanned, rebooted and installed a new Driver with the Clean Installation option ticked.